# Civi Event - Event Title & Event Name with French accents not saving in correct encoding

Tags: civievent, database

Database/environment is set to UTF-8. This just started happening and we can't figure out why.

In the example below, a French title and summary are given -- when saved, the Title appears to be saved properly with the correct accents, but the Event Title field value converts the accented characters.

The Event Description area saves accents fine (it has TINYMCE enabled).

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You say "just started happening" - perhaps you can review previous events and identify the point in time where CiviCRM started corrupting event titles? That might help you track down the cause of the change?

Comment: Do these fields also look funny on the display page (i.e., not just the form)? The db settings are irrelevant by the way, assuming it's just how they're being displayed on this page. I'd guess it's the container html that's not declaring the text as utf-8 as it should, maybe some change in the CMS triggered the problem.

Comment: Hey Alan, I posted a more detailed explanation in a new post here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/event-contribution-page-2-doctype-declarations-characters-with-accents-not-ou

Comment: Updated question with more details posted here: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/event-contribution-page-2-doctype-declarations-characters-with-accents-not-ou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, we figured out the issue.

We discovered it was caused by the Front End Page Options +  Entity Settings Helper Extension.

I believe the extensions were only meant for 4.4 (we are on 4.6).